# How can I get a hash list of unverified NFT's created by a specific update authority or creator address from the CLI?

Tags: cli, spl-token-cli, metaboss

How can I get all of the unverified NFT's via the CLI from a recent airdrop? By creator address or update authority because there's no candy machine. I need a list so I can sign/verify, or null them.

This happened because the RPC endpoint was intermittently failing (quicknode). This caused the signing transaction after the mint to fail sometimes. Leaving me with a bunch of unverified ones!

I have tried metaboss and the ME hashlist tool. But these are only returning verified ones.